Create an fdf or xfdf file from excel via vba
I am trying to create a macro that can use the comments I created in excel and either make an annotation in a pdf file or create an xfdf/fdf so then I can import the comments generated into a pdf report. Any help is appreciated, I have tried to create annotations but does not like when I try to run it with acrobat. I do have exchange and try that option but just manage to open the software and not the file.
Any help is appreciated.
Sub Import_Commment
Function text_annotation(FileName, path, Proj_No, Dept_no, New_tag, sizex, sizey)
    Dim pdDoc As Object
    Dim app As Object
    Dim jso As Object
    Dim point(2) As Integer
    Dim popupRect(3) As Integer
    Dim rect(3) As Integer
    Dim pageRect As Object
    Dim annot As Object
    Dim props As Object
    Dim text As Object

    Set pdDoc = Nothing
    Set app = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set pdDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    FileName = Range(“Q2”).Value & ".pdf"
          folder = Replace(Range("Q2").Value, "/", "\")
          path = Environ("HomeDrive") & Environ("HomePath") & "\OneDrive - NAME\" & folder & "\" 
    fullpath = path & FileName
    pdDoc.Open (fullpath)
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

    If Not jso Is Nothing Then
        Set page = pdDoc.AcquirePage(0)
        Set pageRect = page.GetSize
        Set annot = jso.AddAnnot

        ' Set annotation properties
        Set props = annot.getprops
        props.page = 0
        props.Name = "Entry_Stamp"
        props.Type = "FreeText"
        props.rect = popupRect
        props.Author = "user"
        props.Width = 1#
        props.strokeColor = jso.color.blue
        props.contents = "text mesg"

        ' Modify font properties (adjust as needed)
        props.textSize = 24
        ' props.textcolor = jso.color.red
        ' props.textFont = "Font.Helv"

        annot.setProps props
    End If
End Function
End Sub


This works for me to add an annotation:
Sub Tester()
'Function text_annotation(FileName, path, Proj_No, Dept_no, New_tag, sizex, sizey)
    Dim pdDoc As Object, avDoc As Object
    Dim app As Object, jso As Object
    Dim point(2) As Integer
    Dim popupRect(3) As Integer
    Dim rect(3) As Integer
    Dim pageRect As Object, Page As Object, annot As Object
    Dim props As Object, text As Object

    Set app = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    app.Show 'make visible
    Set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.avDoc")
    
    avDoc.Open "C:\Temp\stories.pdf", ""
    avDoc.BringToFront
    Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc 'reference the document

    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

    If Not jso Is Nothing Then
        Set Page = pdDoc.AcquirePage(0)
        Set pageRect = Page.GetSize
        Set annot = jso.AddAnnot()

        ' Set annotation properties
        Set props = annot.getprops
        props.Page = 0
        props.Name = "Entry_Stamp"
        props.Type = "FreeText"
        popupRect(0) = 340  ' x lower left
        popupRect(1) = 35  ' y lower left
        popupRect(2) = 440 ' x upper right
        popupRect(3) = 55   ' y upper right
        props.rect = popupRect
        props.Author = "user"
        props.Width = 1#
        props.strokeColor = jso.Color.blue
        props.contents = "text mesg"
        annot.setProps props
    End If
    
    pdDoc.Save 1, "C:\Temp\stories_annot.pdf" 'save annotated copy 1 = PDSaveFull
    pdDoc.Close
    
End Sub


Hi Tim, will havea go and let yoy know, thank you in advance.
